# Problem with RecyclerView in BottomsheetFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-bottomsheetdialog

i am trying to create a bottom sheet fragment with a recycler view. But i am getting an error in recycler view as `adapter not set skipping layout`

I am positive that i set the adapter for recycler view.I do not seem to understand the problem.

Bottomsheet Fragment code

```
public class QueueBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    //Views
    private View fragmentView;
    private RecyclerView queueRecyclerView;
    private QueueRecyclerAdapter queueRecyclerAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.queue_bottomsheet,container,false);

        Initialize();
        populateSongs();

        return fragmentView;
    }

    private void Initialize(){
        queueRecyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.queue_recyclerView);
        queueRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    private void populateSongs(){
        queueRecyclerAdapter = new QueueRecyclerAdapter(getContext(),MusicService.songsSet);
        queueRecyclerView.setAdapter(queueRecyclerAdapter);
        queueRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

Code for recycler adapter

```
public class QueueRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QueueRecyclerAdapter.QueueViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private SongSet songSet;

    public QueueRecyclerAdapter(Context context,SongSet songSet){
        this.context = context;
        this.songSet = songSet;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public QueueViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.queue_cardview,parent,false);
        return new QueueViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QueueViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.songTv.setText(songSet.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.artistTv.setText(songSet.get(position).getArtist());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songSet.size();
    }

    public static class QueueViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView songTv;
        private TextView artistTv;

        public QueueViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            songTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sName);
            artistTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.aName);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling like this in my main activity

```
queueBottomSheetDialog queueBottomSheetDialog = newQueueBottomSheetDialog();
queueBottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"QUEUE BOTTOMSHEET");
```

Comment: try doing `setLayoutManager` before `setAdapter`

Comment: did it not working

Comment: Did you check answers on https://stackoverflow.com/q/29141729/6891563

Comment: I am getting this problem only in Bottom Dialog Fragment. In normal fragments i implemented recycler views without any problem.